# How can I rotate the capsule only on the Y?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

RotateTo is call from the Update. I want it to rotate on the Y only.
now it seems like it's rotating on all axis X,Y,Z

```
private void RotateTo()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(capsule.position, curvedLinePoints[rotationIndex].transform.position);
        if(distance < 0.1f)
        {
            rotationIndex++;
        }

        // Determine which direction to rotate towards
        Vector3 targetDirection = curvedLinePoints[rotationIndex].transform.position -capsule.position;

        // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
        float singleStep = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Rotate the forward vector towards the target direction by one step
        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(capsule.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);

        // Calculate a rotation a step closer to the target and applies rotation to this object
        capsule.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
    }
```

This is the full script.

The transform is moving along g waypoints there are more than 4000 waypoints the capsule should only rotate looking each time to the next curvedLinePoint from the List curvedLinePoints.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class WaypointsFollower : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Waypoints waypoints;
    public Transform capsule;
    public bool go;
    public bool goForward;
    public float rotationSpeed;

    private int index = 0;
    private int rotationIndex = 0;
    private int counter = 0;
    private int c = 0;
    private List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints = new List<GameObject>();

    public int numofposbetweenpoints;

    private bool getonce;
    private bool getBackwardIndexOnce = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.Find("Waypoints").GetComponent<Waypoints>();

        curvedLinePoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line Point").ToList();

        if(waypoints.moveInReverse == false)
        {
            goForward = true;
        }
        else
        {
            goForward = false;
        }

        if(goForward)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (getonce == false)
        {
            numofposbetweenpoints = curvedLinePoints.Count;

            getonce = true;
        }

        if (go == true && waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count > 0)
        {
            if(goForward == false && getBackwardIndexOnce)
            {
                index = waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count - 1;

                getBackwardIndexOnce = false;
            }

            RotateTo();

            Move();
        }
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;

            // error exception out of bound on line 55 to check !!!!!
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index], distanceToTravel);

            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);

            if (newPos == waypoints.lineRendererPositions[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= waypoints.lineRendererPositions.Count - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne)
                    {
                        index++;
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;

                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne)
                    {
                        index--;

                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;

                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;
    }

    private void RotateTo()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(capsule.position, curvedLinePoints[rotationIndex].transform.position);
        if(distance < 0.1f)
        {
            rotationIndex++;
        }

        // Determine which direction to rotate towards
        Vector3 targetDirection = curvedLinePoints[rotationIndex].transform.position -capsule.position;

        // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
        float singleStep = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Rotate the forward vector towards the target direction by one step
        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(capsule.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);

        // Calculate a rotation a step closer to the target and applies rotation to this object
        capsule.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the hierarchy the platform is the moving transform in the script and the capsule is the capsule that should only rotate facing each time the next curvedLinePoint. There are over 4000 waypoints but only 10 curvedLinePoints. a bit confusing. The capsule should rotate facing each time the next curvedLinePoint while the transform is moving along the waypoints.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnAun.jpg)

I tried this now :

```
private void RotateTo()
    {
        var distance = Vector3.Distance(capsule.position, curvedLinePoints[rotationIndex].transform.position);
        if(distance < 0.1f)
        {
            rotationIndex++;
        }

        var lookPos = curvedLinePoints[rotationIndex].transform.position - capsule.position;
        lookPos.y = 0;
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(lookPos);
        capsule.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(capsule.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
```

and it's rotating bu when I'm looking on the capsule I don't see any of the axis pointing the next point for example in this screenshot the blue is facing to the right the green up the red more ore less down while the point it's moving to is on the left cube so the capsule rotates but why none of the axis is pointing at its direction?

[Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRjvS.jpg)

I also added eyes to the capsule on the blue axis thinking the blue axis is forward but the capsule is rotating the eyes are never facing the next target.

This screenshot is just to show the eyes on the blue axis direction.

[Eyes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT37v.jpg)

Comment: What is the goal of this code? What is `curvedLinePoints[]`?

Comment: @ken The goal is to rotate the capsule facing each time the next curvedLinePoint from the List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints I want the capsule to rotate smoothly facing the next curvedLinePoint. I will edit with the full script. It's confusing.

Comment: @ken updated my question again with some more screenshots.

Comment: I will try to answer your question as soon as possible. @Shi    (I can’t say your full name or else it bleeps it out.)

Comment: @ken Thank you.

Comment: can you either add a gif, or describe what your game is. I still don't understand what you mean. Can you try to make a long edit to your question or add a long comment. I didn't get the comment you posted above.